# listview setSelectionFromTop too much work on main thread

Tags: android, listview

I want to align another `ListView` (List2) based on first `ListView` (List1) position.

I do this using the method,

```
list2.setSelectionFromTop(list1.getFirstVisiblePosition(), view.getChildAt(0).getTop());
```

This call blocks the UI thread untill this is printed on the logcat,

```
I/Choreographer(16328): Skipped 65 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

I cannot do this operation on a different thread other than main thread since its updating the UI. I tried using Handler.post, Handler.postDelayed, but no use.
Is there a way to stop this operation if it takes long.

Comment: You need to provide more details.  This seems like it should be a trivial operation but evidentally something is going wrong. Have you tried a little debugging, such as simply tracing the two parameters but not making the call to setSelectionFromTop?  That would help isolate the problem.

Comment: I use two listviews, when I scroll List1, I pass the event to List2 (so it scrolls too). Once the scroll operation is complete, I want to keep both in sync using setSelectionFromTop

Comment: Yes, I understand. Another thing to consider: are you sure the event is passed only when the scrolling is finished?